# How to populate 'New Document' from an existing library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, document, folder

I am just learning SharePoint.

Basically, I have a site with 2 libraries. One is a "Master Documentation" library and the other is a "Project" library where a PM will create a document set folder and once in there I would like the PM to have the ability to navigate to Document > New Document however instead of "new document" it would be a list of documents that were uploaded to the Master Documentation library.

I hope that's understandable and I apologise if it is a very simple question, again just new to this without any training !

Comment: Sorry just to add - this is SharePoint 2010 and I have access to designer if needs be!

Comment: As understand from you quest you need to build a relation between Master and Project library is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

As understand from you quest you need to build a relation between Master and Project library ? So to do that

- try to create a lookup field from your Master Library to project Library. to select it's related doc.
- Open library settings > Create a new column.
- Select its type as lookup type.
- select the master Library and show it's title .
- select multiple value if you need.
- specify also the related column.

[image]

Now when you create a new project and at your form you can select its related documents from master library.